# Using join query in SQL Server get result

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables as you can see I have mentioned below, `CaseID` in relation with primary key and foreign key, so I want result whose action is 1 and in second table queue is not equals to 7, but my result is giving me 2 records and according to my condition record should be one, and it return is only CaseID 3. so could you please what is mistake in my query.

```
 CaseID action
  1      1
  2      0
  3      1
  4      0

 Cid CaseID Queue
 1   1      1
 2   1      2
 3   1      7
 4   3      1
 5   3      2
 6   4      3
 7   4      6
 8   2      4
 9   2      5
```

Query:

```
 select 
     CaseTblA.CaseID 
 from 
     CaseTblA
 inner join 
     CaseTblB on CaseTblA.CaseID = CaseTblB.CaseID
 where 
     CaseTblA.Action = 1 and CaseTblB.Queue <> 7
 group by 
     CaseTblA.CaseID
```

This query returns :

```
 CaseID
 1
 3
```

but it should be return :

```
 CaseID
 3
```

Comment: You have two matches fitting your condition here `(1,1,1),
 (2,1,2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
SELECT        CaseTblA.CaseID
FROM            CaseTblB INNER JOIN
                         CaseTblA ON CaseTblB.CaseID = CaseTblA.CaseID
  INNER JOIN 
                         (select CaseID, MAX(Queue) as maxqueue
                         from CaseTblB
                         group by CaseID
                         Having MAX(Queue) <> 7) a on 
                         a.CaseID = CaseTblA.CaseID
where CaseTblA.Action = 1 
GROUP BY CaseTblA.CaseID
```